# Activity's LiveData leaking a Fragment

Tags: android, android-livedata, leakcanary

I am currently "Leak hunting" within my app and noticed some strange reports from LeakCanary. I have a `LiveData` field named `appBarVerticalOffset` within my Activity and a child Fragment who is registering as an observer to it (code below). According to LeakCanary, this observer lambda is leaking the entire fragment but I don't see how that is possible based on my understanding of `viewLifecycleOwner`.

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    MyLog.d(logTag, "Lifecycle: onViewCreated()")

    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    // Leak detected stemming from here
    requireMainActivity().appBarVerticalOffset.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
        if (ignoreAppBarInsets) return@observe
        lastAppBarOffset = it
        updateTopMargin(lastInset + lastAppBarOffset)
    }
}
```

Here's the leak trace from LeakCanary

```
┬───
│ GC Root: Local variable in native code
│
├─ in instance
│    Leaking: NO (MainActivity↓ is not leaking)
│    Thread name: 'Measurement Worker'
│    ↓ in.a
├─ io instance
│    Leaking: NO (MainActivity↓ is not leaking)
│    ↓ is.v
├─ ir instance
│    Leaking: NO (MainActivity↓ is not leaking)
│    a instance of com.ggstudios.lolcatalyst.MainApplication
│    ↓ ir.C
├─ kj instance
│    Leaking: NO (MainActivity↓ is not leaking)
│    f instance of com.ggstudios.lolcatalyst.activity.MainActivity with
│    mDestroyed = false
│    ↓ kj.f
├─ com.ggstudios.lolcatalyst.activity.MainActivity instance
│    Leaking: NO (Activity#mDestroyed is false)
│    mApplication instance of com.ggstudios.lolcatalyst.MainApplication
│    mBase instance of androidx.appcompat.view.ContextThemeWrapper
│    ↓ MainActivity.appBarVerticalOffset
│                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
├─ androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 447 B in 17 objects
│    ↓ LiveData.mObservers
│               ~~~~~~~~~~
├─ androidx.arch.core.internal.SafeIterableMap instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 388 B in 14 objects
│    ↓ SafeIterableMap.mStart
│                      ~~~~~~
├─ androidx.arch.core.internal.SafeIterableMap$Entry instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 36 B in 2 objects
│    ↓ SafeIterableMap$Entry.mKey
│                            ~~~~
├─ com.ggstudios.lolcatalyst.activity.abs.
│  -$$Lambda$BaseFragment$0sNhbeEaSQNsxxw_P7fp-bJGs1k instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 12 B in 1 objects
│    ↓ -$$Lambda$BaseFragment$0sNhbeEaSQNsxxw_P7fp-bJGs1k.f$0
│                                                         ~~~
╰→ com.ggstudios.lolcatalyst.champions_screen.ChampionsFragment instance
​     Leaking: YES (ObjectWatcher was watching this because com.ggstudios.
​     lolcatalyst.champions_screen.ChampionsFragment received
​     Fragment#onDestroy() callback and Fragment#mFragmentManager is null)
​     Retaining 4.5 kB in 156 objects
​     key = 1f344f3c-e635-4453-b740-e201d0023b83
​     watchDurationMillis = 23040
​     retainedDurationMillis = 18027
METADATA
Build.VERSION.SDK_INT: 30
Build.MANUFACTURER: Google
LeakCanary version: 2.6
App process name: com.ggstudios.lolcatalyst
Stats: LruCache[maxSize=3000,hits=8529,misses=114956,hitRate=6%]
RandomAccess[bytes=6161965,reads=114956,travel=56509632020,range=31197327,size=3
8322816]
Heap dump reason: 2 retained objects, app is not visible
Analysis duration: 10775 ms
```